# Magento2 controllers: Method executeInternal

Tags: magento2, controllers

I just pulled a fresh copy of Magento 2 (1.0.0-beta5) and the extensions that I've worked on don't work anymore.
That doesn't surprise me. It usually happens like that. But this time is different.

I got this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   [Namespace][Module]\Controller\Adminhtml\Module\Validate contains 1
>   abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement
>   the remaining methods
>   (Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::executeInternal) in
>   app/code/[Namespace][Module]/Controller/Adminhtml/Module/Validate.php
>   on line 30

The error message is straight forward. I need to implement an abstract method.
What I don't get is, what does this method `executeInternal` supposed to do.
I have a hunch is a replacement for the old `execute` method that is what gets executed for a controller action.
But I see that method `execute` is still there and now requires a `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` parameter.
Can someone explain what `executeInternal` does and what does `execute` do now?

Comment: That change got to develop by mistake. The revert change will be in merged soon. So please disregard, or use earlier commit.

Comment: @AntonKril. Please add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That change got to develop by mistake. The revert change will be in merged soon. So please disregard, or use earlier commit.

Comment: but will executeInternal be merged in for GA?